# How to change all front decimal to 0 in php

Tags: php

I have some data from database like this :

```
43966.31875
```

how to change `43966` to `0` and keep decimal number to `31875`, What should I do?

well, for the final result like this :

```
0.31875
```

***If my explanation is incomprehensible, I apologize, and you can ask me again, Thank You***

Comment: `$number - intval($number)`?

Comment: sorry, why is the result of my data 0? I have made it as you said

Comment: Can you share a bit more details? Like what the data is (e.g. a `var_dump` of the value), what you tried, and what you're getting

Comment: sorry, I made a little mistake, what you said is working for me, but why the result is `0.31874999999854`, should the result is `0.31875`

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Try this. This is exactly what you needed

     $number = 43966.31875;
     $result = floatval(strrchr($number, "."));
     echo $result;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex method:

```
$string = '43966.31875';
echo preg_replace('/(\d+).(\d+)/i', '0.${2}', $string);
```

> Will split number into 2 parts then replace the part 1 with "0."

The strstr method:

```
$string = '43966.31875';
echo '0'.strstr($string, '.');
```

> Also split the number into 2 parts and take the second part and add "0" before

Comment: the result is not return to `0.31875` but the result is `0.31874999999854`, I still confused why my result return to `0.31874999999854` and not return to `0.31875` :(

Comment: I updated my answer, please try regex method @LuckALip

Comment: Also update strstr function method

Comment: okay I will try what you said, thanks to help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213915/discussion-between-luckalip-and-huy-trnh).

Answer (score 1):

```php
$number = 43966.31875;
$decimalPart = fmod($number, 1);

$decimalCount = explode('.', $number)[1];
$result = round($decimalPart, strlen($decimalCount));
```

Refer the Official Documentation: 
[PHP fmod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php)

Comment: This will return **0.31874999999854**